# Blob Storage based Azure Function Trigger is not working with Storage Explorer/Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I need to write an azure function that compress any files uploaded in the azure blob storage.

With this Connection String

[image]

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

it throws the following error

```
[2022-05-26T21:44:56.133Z] An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.
[2022-05-26T21:44:56.138Z] Azure.Storage.Blobs: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:4ddeb612-680e-40f0-8d62-ac754fe791e7
Time:2022-05-26T21:44:55.988Z
[2022-05-26T21:44:56.141Z] Status: 400 (The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.)
```

It works fine with Azure Storage Account Connection string. What am I missing in the local emulator?

Comment: Try to downgrafe Azure.Storage.Blobs to 12.10.0 (if you are suing it) - I am having issues with newer versions (12.12.0)

Answer (score 1):

For the local emulator, you don't really require a "Connection String". You can set `AzureWebJobsStorage` to "UseDevelopmentStorage=true". Here is how my local.settings.json look like -

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

REFERENCES:
[Use Azurite emulator for local Azure Storage development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio#connection-strings)